# bindfs, osfuse, sshfs & macOS Sierra

Tags: homebrew, mount, macos, sftp

I use bindfs with osxfuse and sshfs to mount specific folders (chroot) to allow sftp access for external users (macOS Sierra 10.12).

Binding a readOnly folder for the user "sftpusr" is done with

```
bindfs -r -u sftpusr /volume/folder /chroot/folder
```

The folder is correctly bound, I can login using sftp and listing the folder once only - then folders and files disappear, I need to mount and bind again.

There is no difference in using either homebrew to install osfuse, sshfs, bindfs or making my "own" binaries.

I had this feature running for years (Mavericks, Yosemite). Is this an incompatibility with macOS Sierra?

Comment: Please add (a) related error message(s) (from the various log files)

Comment: I can't find anything in /var/log/* which would point to a bindfs, osfuse or sshfs error; the first attempt to read a bindfs folder is good, the second shows an empty folder only. bindfs is still active as a I cannot mount a folder again without having umounted, as this error message point out.

fuse: failed to mount file system: Undefined error: 0
mount_osxfuse: mount point /sftp/folder is itself on a OSXFUSE volume

Comment: Do you have a quick how-to/receipt (e.g. a link) how to set up the services or is it as easy as installing all three (with homebrew) and it works? Then I will install it in a OS X VM and do my best to solve your problem!

Comment: OK I installed it and got it to work locally but not via remote sftp user: `sudo bindfs -o local,allow_other,debug,volname=DefaultWeb -u sftpuser /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default /chroot/sftpuser/scratchpad` (just a reminder)

Answer (score 1):

I had no luck getting bindfs and osfuse up and running with macOS Sierra. So I configured a virtual machine instead on top of CentOS 7, with everything running now.

https://bernhard.hensler.net/sftp-yosemite-server/